# Uncaught TypeError Porto Theme 2.1.0 Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, console

I'm using porto theme 2.1.0 in my Magento 2. Every time i load my site I'm always experiencing this error.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should ask developers of Porto Theme to fix problem

Comment: Thanks but I tried that but got no response. that's why I was hoping that someone might answer my problem in here.

Comment: It seems that jQuery is not implemented. Did you try to execute `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` ?

Comment: Yeah I initiated that command but it keeps coming back after a day.

Comment: @MazeStricks have you managed to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes I have managed to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi @MazeStricks, Did You get any solution? please share.